# SIGSEGV Running Monotouch on iOS6

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, ios6

We recently tried compiling our MonoTouch application for iOS6, and it invariably crashes about 5 seconds after pressing play in the main menu.

Here's the stack trace:

```
Stacktrace:
  at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ConstructNSObject (intptr,intptr) [0x00007] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:208
  at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject (intptr) [0x0001f] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:259
  at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObjectWrapped (intptr) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:276
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObjectWrapped (intptr) <0xffffffff>
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
  at Resistor5.Program.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in /Users/nullcandy/Projects/Resistor5/Resistor5_iOS/AppDelegate.cs:22
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_dynamic (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:

0   Resistor5_iOS                       0x011bf7b4 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 280
1   Resistor5_iOS                       0x011a9380 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 268
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x31e17e93 _sigtramp + 42
3   ???                                 0x00000000 0x0 + 0
4   Resistor5_iOS                       0x0126191c single_arg_user_copy_or_mark + 28
5   Resistor5_iOS                       0x0128e4cc mark_tls_slots + 160
6   Resistor5_iOS                       0x012650f4 scan_from_registered_roots + 412
7   Resistor5_iOS                       0x01271c34 major_collection + 3040
8   Resistor5_iOS                       0x01272c98 minor_collect_or_expand_inner + 88
9   Resistor5_iOS                       0x012733a0 mono_gc_alloc_obj_nolock + 1336
10  Resistor5_iOS                       0x01262db0 mono_gc_alloc_vector + 136
11  Resistor5_iOS                       0x01249cf4 mono_array_new_specific + 132
12  Resistor5_iOS                       0x0108abb4 wrapper_managed_to_native_object___icall_wrapper_mono_array_new_specific_intptr_int + 68
13  Resistor5_iOS                       0x00088090 MonoTouch_ObjCRuntime_Runtime_GetNSObject_intptr + 144
14  Resistor5_iOS                       0x00088110 MonoTouch_ObjCRuntime_Runtime_GetNSObjectWrapped_intptr + 28
15  Resistor5_iOS                       0x000b8620 wrapper_native_to_managed_MonoTouch_ObjCRuntime_Runtime_GetNSObjectWrapped_intptr + 64
16  Resistor5_iOS                       0x012bd634 get_managed_object_for_ptr_fast + 108
17  Resistor5_iOS                       0x011a19f4 native_to_managed_trampoline_MonoTouch_UIKit_UIAccelerometer__UIAccelerometerDelegate_DidAccelerate + 324
18  UIKit                               0x35f16717 <redacted> + 222
19  UIKit                               0x35ca7359 <redacted> + 2820
20  UIKit                               0x35ca66d5 <redacted> + 72
21  UIKit                               0x35ca6123 <redacted> + 6154
22  GraphicsServices                    0x33f395a3 <redacted> + 590
23  GraphicsServices                    0x33f391d3 <redacted> + 34
24  CoreFoundation                      0x36311173 <redacted> + 34
25  CoreFoundation                      0x36311117 <redacted> + 138
26  CoreFoundation                      0x3630ff99 <redacted> + 1384
27  CoreFoundation                      0x36282ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
28  CoreFoundation                      0x36282d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
29  GraphicsServices                    0x33f382eb GSEventRunModal + 74
30  UIKit                               0x35cfa301 UIApplicationMain + 1120
31  Resistor5_iOS                       0x000b769c wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 240
32  Resistor5_iOS                       0x0094d158 Resistor5_Program_Main_string__ + 152
33  Resistor5_iOS                       0x01085ce0 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 200
34  Resistor5_iOS                       0x011ab3dc mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1644
35  Resistor5_iOS                       0x0124aa8c mono_runtime_invoke + 128
36  Resistor5_iOS                       0x0124ec84 mono_runtime_exec_main + 436
37  Resistor5_iOS                       0x0124f044 mono_runtime_run_main + 756
38  Resistor5_iOS                       0x011aff14 mono_jit_exec + 140
39  Resistor5_iOS                       0x012b7f88 main + 2028
40  Resistor5_iOS                       0x000020c4 start + 52

=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

It works fine with iOS5. Any ideas?

P.S. Although the accelerometer is mentioned in the stacktrace, we're not using the accelerometer at any point in the code.

Comment: In your bug report please state if you're using `sgen` or the (default) `bohem` garbage collector.

Comment: It turns out we had changed to sgen at some point a little while ago. Changing it back to the default fixed the crash.

Comment: Would it be possible to fill a bug report with a test case ? (if can be marked as private) as we're already investigating a similar issue and any extra details could prove very useful to us. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like memory corruption - I suggest you [file a bug report](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) with a test case / your entire project.